# printing all function calls in a php script

Tags: php, debugging

I am wondering if it is possible to print on screen all functions that are called in a php script.

This might imply the possibility to override the default behaviour associated to all function calls, which means defining some additional behaviour to what happens when a function is called.

For example, if I have the following functions:

```
function foo() {
  echo "hi";
}

function additional_behaviour($function_name) {
  echo "function $function_name has been called";
}
```

Somehow I would like enrich the behaviour associated to **all** function calls in order to obtain something like this:

```
> foo();
function foo has been called
hi
```

Comment: I'm not 100% but http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php might help

Comment: @JonathonHenderson : that function is used to print a backtrace at a specific point. I want to print on screen all function calls.

Comment: Tools like xhprof or xdebug for profiling provide this functionality

Comment: I'm not really clear what you mean by *"...imply the possibility to override the default behaviour associated to all function calls."* Can you clarify that please?

Comment: @francescostablum Could you not put this function at the end of execution? The backtrace allows you to track which functions were called

Comment: @francescostablum Or do you mean all PHP function calls as well as user defined?

Comment: @JonathonHenderson : I mean all function calls. Or at least those that are user-defined.

Answer (score 2):

> I am wondering if it is possible to print on screen all functions that are called in a php script

You can use a tool such as [xDebug](http://www.xdebug.org/) to provide you with a profiler trace. Then you can use KCacheGrind to view the profiler data, which will tell you about every function call that was made during a program run, including a detailed analysis of the time taken, etc.